# pull Else if from SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need the data to have a different style if the sold = 0 in the mysql table 
and when i use the code below the website shows a blank white page

(?=$vehicle-> this is the vehicle reference
and sold is the column withing the sql table

```
<?php
 if (?=$vehicle->sold?!= 1)                     
    {
    <div class="foo">
       <div class="fboverlay"></div>
       <a>
         <a href="/listing/<?=$vehicle->vehicle_id?>"><img src="/media.php?productId=<?=$vehicle->vehicle_id?>&file=<?=$vehicle->main_image?>" /></a>

       </a>
    </div>
    }        
     else {
          <a href="/listing/<?=$vehicle->vehicle_id?>"><img src="/media.php?productId=<?=$vehicle->vehicle_id?>&file=<?=$vehicle->main_image?>" /></a>       
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You could take just a _little_ care over making this post presentable and useful. What is the problem? Why is your syntax so wildly incorrect? Why is the indentation and formatting all over the place? You couldn't even be bothered to use a capital letter and full stop. So, well, frankly, then I can't be bothered to answer it. Sorry.

Comment: `?=$vehicle->vehicle_id?` You seem to be under the impression that `?=` is part of the variable name. It's not. `<?= .. ?>` is a shorthand for outputting a thing. `$vehicle->vehicle_id` is how you access the variable. Which PHP book are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn the PHP from the basics. Learn about operators, PHP and HTML secion, etc..
Anyway, i fixed your code. The condition is if `$vehicle->sold` is not equal to 1. But i think, (in your OP you mentioned it should be 0) you want this: `$vehicle->sold == 0`

```
//Use sytnax like this. See php opeartors.
if ($vehicle->sold != 1) {
    ?> <!-- Close the php -->
    <div class = "foo">
        <div class = "fboverlay"></div>
            <a href = "/listing/<?= $vehicle->vehicle_id ?>"><img src = "/media.php?productId=<?= $vehicle->vehicle_id ?>&file=<?= $vehicle->main_image ?>" /></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    //Open the php again
} else {
    ?> <!-- close the php -->
    <a href = "/listing/<?= $vehicle->vehicle_id ?>"><img src = "/media.php?productId=<?= $vehicle->vehicle_id ?>&file=<?= $vehicle->main_image ?>" /></a>
<?php //Open again
}
```

Comment: The HTML is still invalid.

Comment: Thx, i will edit. removed the <a></a>. Do you see any error now?

Comment: Thank you very much that has worked fine im quite a noob at writing php and im taking the website over from a previous developer with no hand over at all

Comment: i Just had to use $vehicle->sold == 0 which is what you said in the responce

Comment: Missing `alt`s but I think we can forgive that here.